# Exporting Wrap Deformed object from Maya to unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, export, maya, 3d-modelling

I would like to know if we can somehow export wrap deformed object from Maya to unity 3d because rigging at the moment is causing some serious problems. If i could somehow export a wrap deformed object to unity3d then it would literally save a lot of work.

Lemme know if anyone knows anything about it.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

from my experience unity won't support custom deform objects. So you probably need to consider converting them to a skincluster there few scripts available to be able to do this. But probably you need to adjust according to your needs. [Check it here](https://www.highend3d.com/maya/script/convert-wrap-deformer-to-skincluster-for-maya)